# How to create a views contextual filter of the current domain

Tags: views, 8, domain-access

I'm using the [domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), but have not enabled the submodule 'domain access' because I'm already using open social group access, and want to prevent performance issues. I only need to filter views 
The domain, domain configuration and domain site settings are enabled.

i added an entityreference field to the 'group' entity type, which allows to choose the domain record.

Now I simply want to have a view that shows groups filtered by domain record, of which the domain is the same as the domain in the current context (as seen in url)

Views contextual filters does not give an option to choose the domain context as default filter.

Not sure if I explained it clearly enough..but how can this be accomplished?

Summarizing:
Domain module installed without domain access submodule
Only have entity reference field in group entities
Want to filter a view of groups by current domain, using contextual filter of the reference field.

Comment: Why can’t you just install the domain access module it comes with a views filter

Comment: If this question is about showing sibling results in Views through ER field, then you need to add the Relationship for the ER field, then add the reverse Relationship, and finally add Contextual filter (ID usually) that is using the second Relationship.